# How can I show a textbox on my BlackBerry application?

Tags: blackberry, textbox

[image]

How can I add a textbox so a user can enter numeric values into my form? I need the borders of the textbox control to be visible at all time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement your own class, inherited from TextBox and override **void paint(Graphics g)** method.

Smth, like that, sorry i write from mobile:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{       
    // set color
    g.setColor(0x555555);
    // draw 100*100 rectangle 
    g.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    // dont forget to invoke 
    super.paint(g);
}
```

If you dont want use overriding,
In OS 4.6+ you can use [Border and BorderFactory](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/index.html) classes (search in All Classes list).

```
// Each integer represents the amount of space between the box and border
// The four parameters of an XYEdge object represents each edge, 
XYEdges thickPadding = new XYEdges(10, 10, 10, 10);

// Sample text field with a thick and solid rounded border
// and single solid colour background.
RichTextField simpleField = new RichTextField("Solid rounded border, solid background");

// Create border and background objects 
Border roundedBorder = BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(thickPadding, Border.STYLE_SOLID);

// Set the objects for use
simpleField.setBorder(roundedBorder);

// Add the field to the screen
 add(simpleField);
```

Comment: So your saying the Blackberry doesn't actually have a usable textbox control? :S

Comment: No. It has! But if you want draw borders - you shold draw it by your code. As i know, since OS 4.6 already has BordersFactory or smth like that, but if you want bordered control in OS from  4.5 to 6.0, implement your own inherited(!) class.

Comment: I'm targetting the new Storm models. Can you tell me how to create a nice looking textbox without overriding? My support for older models is needless.